# Crash during scroll on Recyclerview when list size is large

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, load

I load the recyclerview data from the webservice. When the list size is large the activity crashes while scrolling. But the activity crashes only on Lollipop devices. In Marshmellow devices it working good. Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance.

public class ActivityDisplayTasksforRating extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomDatePickerListener {

```
boolean shouldExecuteOnResume;

private RecyclerView recyclerVw_rating;
private TaskRatingAdapter mAdapter;
private LinearLayout lLayout_no_data;
private NetworkClass networkClass = new NetworkClass();
private String mUserId, mStartDate, mEndDate;
private List<TaskApprovalListNew.OverdueRatingReport> mTaskApprovalList = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView btn_Sync, imgVw_menu, imgV_calendarList;
private TextView txtVw_start_end_date,txtVw_dashboardTitle;
private CustomProgress mcustomprogress;
private CircularImageView imgVw_profile_image;
private String mProfile_image_url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
    shouldExecuteOnResume = false;
    getViewCasting(); // Casting the views


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.hasExtra("profile_image"))
    {
        mProfile_image_url = intent.getStringExtra("profile_image");
    }


    if (mProfile_image_url!=null)
    {
        Picasso.with(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this).load(mProfile_image_url).error(R.drawable.zoonooz).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).placeholder(R.drawable.zoonooz).skipMemoryCache().into(imgVw_profile_image);
    }

    txtVw_dashboardTitle.setText("Task Approval List");
    imgV_calendarList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // shows the custom date picker dialog
            CustomDatePicker alertDialog = new CustomDatePicker(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, true, ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this);
            alertDialog.getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    getTaskDataforRating(mStartDate, mEndDate);
}

public void getViewCasting() {
    recyclerVw_rating = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerVw_common);
    lLayout_no_data = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLayout_no_data);
    btn_Sync = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_Sync);
    imgVw_menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVw_menu);
    imgV_calendarList = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV_calendarList);
    txtVw_start_end_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVw_start_end_date);
    txtVw_dashboardTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVw_dashboardTitle);
    imgVw_profile_image = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgVw_profile_image);

    imgV_calendarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgVw_menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn_Sync.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


public void initRecyclerview()
{
    if (mTaskApprovalList.size()>0) {
        System.out.println("=========list size"+mTaskApprovalList.size());

        recyclerVw_rating.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, 1);
        recyclerVw_rating.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new TaskRatingAdapter(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, mTaskApprovalList);
        recyclerVw_rating.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("=========List empty");
        recyclerVw_rating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lLayout_no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void getTaskDataforRating(final String start_date, final String end_date)
{
    try {

        if (NetworkClass.isOnline(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this)) {

            if (mTaskApprovalList.size()>0)
            {
                mTaskApprovalList.clear();
            }

            Retrofit retrofit = networkClass.callretrofit();

            APIInterfaces service = retrofit.create(APIInterfaces.class);

            mUserId = PreferenceConnector.readString(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, PreferenceConnector.USER_ID, "");

            Call<TaskApprovalListNew> call = service.getTasksforApprovalList(mUserId, start_date, end_date); // "6"

            mcustomprogress = new CustomProgress();
            mcustomprogress.showCustomDialog(this);
            mcustomprogress.setText("Fetching data");


            call.enqueue(new Callback<TaskApprovalListNew>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TaskApprovalListNew> call, retrofit2.Response<TaskApprovalListNew> response) {

                    if (response.body() != null) if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        String status = response.body().getStatus();

                        mTaskApprovalList = response.body().getOverdueRatingReport();

                        if (status.equals("NTE_01")) {

                            initRecyclerview();
                        } else {
                            initRecyclerview();
                        }

                        if (mcustomprogress != null) {
                            mcustomprogress.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TaskApprovalListNew> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (mcustomprogress != null) {
                        mcustomprogress.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, "Failure :" + t.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            if (mcustomprogress != null) {
                mcustomprogress.dismiss();
            }
            Toast.makeText(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
}



public class TaskRatingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskRatingAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<TaskApprovalListNew.OverdueRatingReport> mManagerProjectsList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Passing Project List
    public TaskRatingAdapter(Context context, List<TaskApprovalListNew.OverdueRatingReport> project_list) {

        mContext = context;
        this.mManagerProjectsList = project_list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_tasks_for_rating, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        System.out.println("=========Position"+position);
        System.out.println("=========Task Name"+mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getTaskName());


        String profile_image = mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getProfileImage();

        if (profile_image!=null)
        {
            Picasso.with(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this).load(profile_image).error(R.drawable.zoonooz).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).placeholder(R.drawable.zoonooz).skipMemoryCache().into(holder.imgVw_user_image);
        }

        holder.txtVw_author.setText(mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getUserName());
        holder.txtVw_task_title.setText(mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getTaskName());
        holder.txtVw_proj_name.setText(mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getProject_name());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityDisplayTasksforRating.this, TaskRatingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("task_id",mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getTaskId());
                intent.putExtra("total_hours",mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getTotalHours());
                intent.putExtra("user_id",mManagerProjectsList.get(position).getUserId()); // Passing the task_id, total_hours and user id to sync activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mManagerProjectsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtVw_task_title,txtVw_proj_name,txtVw_author,txtVw_task_day,txtVw_task_month,txtVw_task_year,txtVw_task_start_time;;
        private CircularImageView imgVw_user_image;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtVw_task_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_task_title);
            txtVw_proj_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_proj_name);
            txtVw_author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_author);
            txtVw_task_day = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_task_day);
            txtVw_task_month = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_task_month);
            txtVw_task_year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_task_year);
            txtVw_task_start_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_task_start_time);
            imgVw_user_image = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgVw_user_image);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your code and error logs?

Comment: Plese post your code, otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: In my case app dont throw any exception. Just restart without prompting anything